# Ubuntu shortcuts won't allow to set media keys for custom commands

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys, cmus

I'm trying to set my keyboard's media keys to control my command line player cmus via cmus-remote (pause, prev, next). This works fine with any other keys but the media keys will not register when I'm prompted to push the desired key for a custom shortcut. The media keys do however register just fine when I set them for one of the ubuntu default shortcuts like "play".

Is there a way to get around this limitation? I've tried to edit my dconf and set ctrl + numpad 5 to cmus-remote --pause which works great:

> [org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1]
> binding='KP_5'
> command='cmus-remote --pause'
> name='cmus pause'

Maybe it's enough to simply replace 'binding' with the media pause key? But how can I find out the name that gnome uses for that key?

xev seems to capture the media next key as 'XF86AudioNext' but setting that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this eventually. One big thing that apparently played into this was having to restart gnome/log out of my session after the changes.

Here's the entire rundown if you want to replicate this:

1. Create 3 new custom commands for cmus pause/next/prev with a random shortcut.
2. Open xev and figure out the names of the keys that you want to map to, for me they were XF86AudioPause, XF86AudioNext, XF86AudioPrev
3. Run dconf-editor in terminal and navigate to /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/
4. All the custom* entries are your custom shortcuts. Open them up and replace the random shortcut you set previously with the correct keys.
5. Reboot your system.